# S3 exception on ListObjects

Tags: php, curl, ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to get a list of all objects in a particular folder on S3.

```
$iterator = $client->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Prefix' => '/my/folder/location/',      
));

foreach ($iterator as $object) {
    echo $object['Key'] . "\n";
}
```

However I keep getting the following exception:

**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\Http\Exception\CurlException' with message '[curl] 56: SSL read: error:1408F119:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or bad record mac, errno 0 [url] https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mybucketname.local?prefix=%2Fmy%2Ffolder%2Flocation%2F' in \vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\Aws\Common\Client\AbstractClient.php on line 288**

Have also tried this without passing through the prefix to just list all items in the bucket and I get the same error.  I've seen on some posts that this is because of a mis-match between the region in the client and the region of the bucket but I've set the client to use the Ireland (eu-west-1) region where my files are located but still get this same error.

Comment: Can you tell us about the versions you are using of PHP, cURL, OpenSSL, and AWS SDK for PHP? Does this fail every time? When did it start failing? You might consider looking at the cURL verbose output to help debug this. To do this, add `'curl.options' => array(CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true)` when you instantiate the SDK.

Comment: PHP = 5.4.12, cURL = 7.29.0, OpenSSL = 1.0.1d, AWS PHP SDK 2.6.13, Apache = 2.4.4. All running on WampServer 2.4 on Windows 7. It fails every time I try. I've only started using the ListObjects request so this is my first experience with it.  I had a similar issue with the copy object when copying between the same bucket where I needed to also specify the bucket name in the copy key and it works ok now. I'll have a look at the cURL verbose options to see if that throws up anything.

Comment: Possibly a bug in OpenSSL 1.0.1d. Try upgrading to WampServer 2.5 (see http://scnakandala.blogspot.com/2014/05/phpopenssl-ssl3getrecorddecryption.html) and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I think you have nailed the problem.  I tried this on a staging server running on EC2 which is using OpenSSL 1.0.1 and everything worked as expected. I don't really want to upgrade my WampServer just as this point as it involves too may upgrades to core components that could knock our team out for several days which we can't afford at the moment.  I'm going to try and just upgrade OpenSSL in my WampServer 2.4 for now. Ultimately this is going to force our hand to start looking at Vagrant to align versions of software across the board. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. There various odd things that pop up from time to time with different combinations/versions of operating systems, PHP, cURL, and OpenSSL/NSS. They errors are usually very cryptic like this one. Glad we could find the culprit fairly quickly.